# AMP Google Search Console Validation

Tags: amp-html

I'm using the AMP plugin for wordpress. I followed the Google guideline from [here](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles) but the Search Console tells me that there is a problem with the structured data element for the AMP pages. An example for an AMP page on [my site.](https://www.wezar.de/deal/50-nachlass-auf-colourblock-fledermausshirt-von-cecil/amp/)

The structured data testing tool doesn't find errors. I know that the AMP requirements are more strict but I can't find the problem. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try to validate your AMP pages, the AMP validator comes bundled with the AMP JS library, so it is available on every AMP page out of the box. To validate:

- Open your page in your browser
- Add “#development=1” to the URL, for 
  example,

  http://localhost:8000/released.amp.html#development=1.
- Open the Chrome DevTools console and check for validation errors.

If the AMP validation service detects that there’s something wrong with your page, it won’t get discovered and distributed by third party websites and won’t appear in the Google AMP Cache.

To view validation errors, check it here: https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/validation_errors.html

Answer (score 0):

We use both the Google SC AMP and Chrome Dev environment validation tools.  Using Chrome will give you a better understanding of what needs to be changed as to software code issues.

Google's AMP is for final verification before submission.